Merge one column from multiple tables in an excel sheet
In an excel sheet there are 12 tables (12 months), each with the same amount of rows and columns.
The following is a mock up using four tables:

I want to read the excel sheet, read the first column (date) and the column with a specific header (in this case, d) from each of the 12 tables. I then want to rename the column d to now be the month of the respective table. Finally, I want to then merge each new dataframe on the first column.
That is, using the data in the columns labeled 'date' and 'd' (see image above), I want the end result to look like this:

Because I know the cell range for each table, I was able to use the following code to read the first table then just adjusted the range to match the other tables. See below:
df1 = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', nrows=31, usecols='B,F')
new_name = str(pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', nrows=0, usecols='A'))
df1.rename(columns={'d': new_name}, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', nrows=31, usecols='J,N')
new_name = str(pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', nrows=0, usecols='I'))
df2.rename(columns={'d': new_name}, inplace=True)

Is it possible to do this all as one code?
I have the following code set to merge the data in the end:
#Merge all dataframes
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['date'],
                                            how='outer'), dfs).fillna(0)

Is it possible to do this all as one code?

What do you mean by one code? One line of code? One code block? Given this Excel structure, you would need an iterative process of some kind but can chain/pipe commands together without the multiple variable assignments.
